# Connecting Database over LAN using WAMP

Tags: database, vb.net, wamp, lan

I am working on an application which uses database over network. My application is working fine on my system. But Database is unable to connect over LAN. I allow all the preference in WAMP settings. I added User and grant them privileges required.

The problem is: my application is unable to connect with database but my IP eg: 192.168.0.xxx is opening on the browser in other systems.

Stuck Here Unable to solve issue using google search.
Please Help

Answer (score 1):

I'd try using mySQL workbench or PHP myAdmin to connect from another computer first. Those programs will have troubleshooting guides to help you figure out what is wrong, and if you can connect then the problem is in your application code instead of server configuration.

Comment: You say _I added User and grant them privileges required_ Exactly how did you create this user in MySQL **details please**. Also is your app using this new MySQL User

Comment: I added User to access the database In the **WAMP** . Using Https://Localhost/Phpmyadmin/......  Users tab